# Why is the past tense sometimes used in a sentence together with the present tense?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

Why in the sentence "I used to be in the government service, but am no longer" is the first part used in the past tense, and the second part in the present?

Comment: The first part is about the past, the second is about the current state, i.e. the present.

Comment: *Am no longer* means that the speaker doesn’t work in the government service anymore. The sentence has the same structure as *I **grew up** in Paris but now **live** in the US*.

Comment: The use of the past tense "used to be" indicates that the speaker had a previous job in government service,

while the present tense "am no longer" signifies their current status outside of government service.

Answer (score 1):

Why in the sentence "I used to be in the government service, but am no longer" is the first part used in the past tense, and the second part in the present?

You almost answered your own question, so you have a good intuition about this! It's because the first part is in the past, and the second part is in the present. There isn't a rule preventing a sentence from taking on multiple tenses when there is a reason to do so. Only avoid tense switching when it is done for no reason. Here, there is a clear reason to do this.